# How do I find the position (x,y,z) of a moving object that I have acceleration?

Tags: integration

I'm writing a program on my phone which capture the phone's accelerometer.

I've been told to sum the acceleration values ( for each values, sum every previous values ) to get the velocity, and do the same process to get position, and for each axis ( x y z )

My acceleration values are stored in an array and are separated by equal amounts of time.

The problem is... I'm getting odd result.

Here is my plotted data : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVWZO.jpg

On each graph there's the maximum value and minimum values, this should help for scaling.

I apologize for poorly drawn graphs as this is for school and I have been instructed not to use any sort of libraries.

These graphs represent me doing circles rotating on the Y axis. As you can see, the Positions graph are wrong. The Z position should go up and down, but in my case it just goes up with a few going down.

What is causing this? Is this normal? Are the acceleration values wrong from the start? What do you think overall ?

If it helps, here's the function in Javascript that I used to integrate/sum

```
function sum_integral(t) {
    res = [];
    res[0] = 0;
    len = t.length;
    for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        res[i] = res[i - 1] + t[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

And here's the graphs when... the phone isn't moving at all : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqW3q.jpg

Comment: What does Z look like when you drop the phone? (onto something soft like a pillow, don't be rash)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bwWiSNC this is me dropping it 3 times and picking it up after each drop, https://imgur.com/a/ruBb69I this is me dropping it once, and stop the recording before picking it up

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get position via discrete sampling of acceleration is Highly Problematic; even if the sampling is perfect, there is no way to definitively reconstruct the continuous version of the object's motion, which means biases can slip in.

Here's an example:  We have a particle moving $x = \sin t$, with velocity $v = x' = \cos t$ and acceleration $a = x'' = -\sin t$.  We'll sample every $0.1$ time units, use constant acceleration for each tick, model the velocity and position accordingly, and then compare to the truth.

[image]

[Source spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14MLDJ6Y_olZa4zt98-URlGhwOklabNnzObZw8ZCUs98/edit?usp=sharing)

Even for this "perfect world" situation, we get errors early on that are several percent of the magnitude.

But the world isn't perfect; the sensors are noisy, have inaccuracies and limited precision, there are all sorts of tiny motions in your hand and so forth that the sensors can either skip over entirely or notice instead of the smooth surroundings.  All these add up to a very, very difficult time deducing positional information from acceleration data.

It also doesn't help that we are basically *always* accelerating already, except that it doesn't feel like it because we live with it for nearly every moment of our lives: **gravity** makes it feel like we are always being pushed upward by the floor, and that counts for the accelerometer in your phone, too: the difference between what it says when you're holding it and what it says as it falls is the acceleration due to gravity.  You'll have to account for that when trying to calculate position, which means figuring out which way is down.

Back a couple decades ago I did some engineering work at an aircraft company, and the main thing I worked on was a helmet-mounted display.  This device needed to have accurate information about its location within the cockpit and orientation so it could, for instance, properly overlay the infrared camera data onto what the pilot would actually see.  Acceleration information was available but useless: the aircraft vibrates heavily, has its own acceleration, and other things, and trying to use it to model position would have the pilot's head allegedly outside the aircraft within seconds.  So we used tuned magnets to detect position directly.

Comment: If I'm reading your graph correctly, you still have a small error margin. If you look at my graph when i'm not even moving the phone, you can clearly see something went wrong

Comment: Oh, yes, there is something I forgot to mention.  One moment...

Comment: I'm taking the acceleration not including gravity, so if an object if perfectly still, the acceleration values I will get should all be zeros ( if I understood correctly ) so it's already been taken care of!